# I am trying to write a simple calculator

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a calculator that takes string as input, for example `"2+4-7/2"`, and calculates it. It is supposed to handle the order of operation.

```
string = '1+1'
module Simple_calculator
  class << self
    def calculate(string)
      operators = [:+, :-, :*, :/]
      res = string
      operators.each do |op|
        splits = string.split(op.to_s)
        if splits.size > 1
          resMap = splits.map do |sp|
            calculate(sp)
          end
          resMap.map(&:to_f).inject(op)
        end
      end
      res.to_f
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Please let us know what error you are getting

Comment: if i provide 2+2 i get 2.0 instead of 4

Comment: Your code only defines a local variable, a module, a class, and a method. It does not do anything useful.

Comment: [Stop trying to write, WRITE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mdy8bFiyzY)

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong in my code?

You're splitting the string by operators, e.g.:

```
"1+2+3".split("+")
#=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

This looks like the wrong approach. Addition, subtraction, multiplication and division are *binary* operations, i.e. they combine *two* elements (operands), not *n* elements.

In your code, 1 + 2 + 3 is treated like:

```
  +
 /|\
1 2 3
```

This makes it much harder to combine the (results of) different operations.

It's easier to treat 1 + 2 + 3 like:

```
  +              +
 / \            / \ 
1   +    or    +   3
   / \        / \
  2   3      1   2
```

Obviously, this can be solved using recursion. Here's a very basic parser / calculator:

```
def parse(string)
  case string
  when /(.*)\+(.*)/ then parse($1) + parse($2)
  when /(.*)\*(.*)/ then parse($1) * parse($2)
  when /^(\d+)$/    then $1.to_i
  else
    raise SyntaxError
  end
end
```

The rules are simple:

1. `/(.*)\+(.*)/` matches `a+b` and returns `parse(a) + parse(b)`
2. `/(.*)\*(.*)/` matches `a*b` and returns `parse(a) * parse(b)`
3. `/^(\d+)$/` matches or more digits and returns the corresponding integer
4. anything else results in a `SyntaxError`

Note that `a` and `b` can be anything, not just numbers.

#### Examples

Digits are turned into numbers (3rd "rule"):

```
parse("1")
#=> "1".to_i
#=> 1

parse("123")
#=> "123".to_i
#=> 123
```

`a+b` is evaluated as `parse(a) + parse(b)`:

```
parse("3+4")
#=> parse("3") + parse("4")
#=>   "3".to_i + "4".to_i
#=>          3 + 4
#=>            7
```

`a+b*c` is evaluated as:

```
parse("1+2*3")
#=> parse("1") + parse("2*3")
#=>   "1".to_i + parse("2*3")
#=>          1 + parse("2*3")
#=>          1 + parse("2") * parse("3")
#=>          1 +   "2".to_i * parse("3")
#=>          1 +          2 * parse("3")
#=>          1 +          2 * "3".to_i
#=>          1 +          2 * 3
#=>          1 +            6
#=>            7
```

The order of operations depends on the matching order. `a+b` matches before `a*b`, therefore:

```
parse("2*3+1")
#=>            parse("2*3") + parse("1")
#=>            parse("2*3") + parse("1")
#=>            parse("2*3") + parse("1")
#=> parse("2") * parse("3") + parse("1")
#=>   "2".to_i * parse("3") + parse("1")
#=>          2 * parse("3") + parse("1")
#=>          2 * "3".to_i   + parse("1")
#=>          2 * 3          + parse("1")
#=>            6            + parse("1")
#=>            6            + "1".to_i
#=>            6            + 1
#=>                         7
```

Comment: Fantastic !  A very insightful solution.  Loved it

Comment: What exactly do the `$1` and `$2` represent? I kind of get it, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @c650 They refer to the capturing groups in the regular expression, i.e. the part enclosed by `(` and `)`. For example: `/(.*)\+(.*)/.match("foo+bar")` returns `#<MatchData "foo+bar" 1:"foo" 2:"bar">` and assigns `"foo"` to `$1` and `"bar"` to `$2`. See [Capturing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) and [Special global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) for details. Another good resource is http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: ... there's also a pretty good online editor / analyzer here: https://regex101.com/r/gF2iS7/1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Stefan. I rarely use regex, but, still: I don't know how I hadn't seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you were returning input instead of result. Here is quick fix for your calculate method. Its working but still need to be rebuild, for ex you can parse string to find operator first and then use it instead of trying to calculate for all operators.

```
def calculate(string)
  operators = [:+, :-, :*, :/]
  operators.map do |op|
    splits = string.split(op.to_s)
    splits.map(&:to_f).inject(op) if splits.size > 1
  end.compact.first
end
```

Happy coding!